# how to "re-enable" special character sequences in javascript?

Tags: javascript, string

If I have a defined String variable as (e.g.) :

```
 var testString="not\\n new line";
```

it's value of course will be `not\n new line`.

But if use directly `"not\n new line"` the test string will contain new line.

So what is the easiest way to turn the **testString** to a string that contains a new line and all other special character sequences that are "disabled" with double backslashes?
Using replaces? It look like it will take a lot of time if it used for unicode characters sequnces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
JSON.parse('"' + testString + '"')
```

will parse JSON and interpret JSON escape sequences which covers all JS escape sequences except `\x` hex, `\v`, and the non-standard octal ones.

People will tell you to `eval` it.  Don't.  `eval` is hugely overpowered for this, and that extra power comes with the risk of XSS vulnerabilities.

```
var jsEscapes = {
  'n': '\n',
  'r': '\r',
  't': '\t',
  'f': '\f',
  'v': '\v',
  'b': '\b'
};

function decodeJsEscape(_, hex0, hex1, octal, other) {
  var hex = hex0 || hex1;
  if (hex) { return String.fromCharCode(parseInt(hex, 16)); }
  if (octal) { return String.fromCharCode(parseInt(octal, 8)); }
  return jsEscapes[other] || other;
}

function decodeJsString(s) {
  return s.replace(
      // Matches an escape sequence with UTF-16 in group 1, single byte hex in group 2,
      // octal in group 3, and arbitrary other single-character escapes in group 4.
      /\\(?:u([0-9A-Fa-f]{4})|x([0-9A-Fa-f]{2})|([0-3][0-7]{0,2}|[4-7][0-7]?)|(.))/g,
      decodeJsEscape);
}
```

Comment: Your `decodeJsString`  seems to work :-) (will test it with unicode characters and will take me some time to understand it) .JSON does not work from scratch for IE9 ...

Answer (score 2):

If you want to express a string *so that Javascript could interpret it* (the equivalent of Python's `repr` function), use `JSON.stringify`:

```
var testString="not\n new line";
console.log(JSON.stringify(testString))
```

will result in "not\n new line" (quotes and all).