# Why are my special characters not ignored in Quoted Batch?

Tags: batch-file, colors, output, echo

I'm trying to create some multiline, multi color ascii art in my batch file, using /|\ characters.

However, I think my batch scrip is reading them as commands instead of outputting text only.

*This is based on some coloring code I found here: [Batch Color per line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7923948/batch-color-per-line)

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=#" %%a in ('"prompt #$H#$E# & echo on & for %%b in (1) do rem"') do (
  set "DEL=%%a"
)
echo TEST

call :ColorText 0a "################################################################################################################################################################"
call :ColorText 1b "^/^|^\" 
call :ColorText 0a "################################################################################################################################################################"

goto :eof

:ColorText
echo off
<nul set /p ".=%DEL%" > "%~2"
findstr /v /a:%1 /R "^$" "%~2" nul
del "%~2" > nul 2>&1
goto :eof
```

The special characters have ^ in front of them, and they are in quotes.

How can I get this to print these special characters for my Ascii Art?

Here is the output I get:

```
F:\>test
TEST
################################################################################
################################################################################
The system cannot find the path specified.
FINDSTR: Cannot open ^^/^^|^^" nul
################################################################################
################################################################################
F:\>
```

Comment: You can not use this method to output a character not allowed in a file name.

Comment: Then, is there any alternate way I can create multiple colours on text that contains these special characters?

Comment: Following your initial linked answer, there is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5344911/2861476). Read the *one year later* section

Comment: Did not see that earlier, but this does work. Thanks!

If you post that as an answer, I will accept it as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You're using obsolete code.  [jeb updated his code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5344911/1683264), then [dbenham updated jeb's update](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10407642/1683264).  Try this:

```
@echo off
setlocal

call :initColorPrint

call :ColorPrint 0a "################################################################################################################################################################"
call :ColorPrint 1b "/|\" 
call :ColorPrint 0a "################################################################################################################################################################"


call :cleanupColorPrint

exit /b

:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

:colorPrint Color  Str  [/n]
setlocal
set "str=%~2"
call :colorPrintVar %1 str %3
exit /b

:colorPrintVar  Color  StrVar  [/n]
if not defined %~2 exit /b
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "str=a%DEL%!%~2:\=a%DEL%\..\%DEL%%DEL%%DEL%!"
set "str=!str:/=a%DEL%/..\%DEL%%DEL%%DEL%!"
set "str=!str:"=\"!"
pushd "%temp%"
findstr /p /A:%1 "." "!str!\..\x" nul
if /i "%~3"=="/n" echo(
exit /b

:initColorPrint
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=#" %%a in ('"prompt #$H#$E# & echo on & for %%b in (1) do rem"') do set "DEL=%%a"
<nul >"%temp%\x" set /p "=%DEL%%DEL%%DEL%%DEL%%DEL%%DEL%.%DEL%"
exit /b

:cleanupColorPrint
del "%temp%\x"
exit /b
```