# How could I draw a pixel in a batch file?

Tags: batch-file, pixel

I want to execute a some commands in .bat file which draws me a pixel, like this :

[image: Link].

If you pay attention to that image, when I execute command "draw", it shows me a pixel.

I want to make a batch file that draw some pixels using this method. It's possible ?

Comment: http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=5266

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6I2XwCIt4ZFRHRBLUItbmlmRnM

This isn't a pixel image, sorry.

Comment: I really hate trying to understand nosense phrases... (Yes, that isn't a pixel image. So?)

Comment: Did you see my image?

Comment: Yes. That is a text-mode image that can be easily displayed using anyone of the methods to show text in color described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4339649/how-to-have-multiple-colors-in-a-windows-batch-file/23956113#23956113), or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7923948/batch-color-per-line/7937132#7937132), etc... What I still don't understand is the relation of such a text image with _this question_ (entitled "How could I draw a pixel in a batch file?").

Comment: Yes, I'm searching how to change the text mode to pixel mode.

Comment: The cmd.exe window is _always_ in text mode, that is, it always display _characters_. However, in the post at the link given in my first comment (entitled "Drawing pixel resolution graphics in text mode") a method that allows to show _individual pixels_ in the screen is shown... Did you reviewed it?

Comment: Yes, I reviewed it, but I don't know how to print a pixel screen like the first image in that post using that programm in the text behind the pixel image...